# .unbind() is not working on event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive Javascript file that is working successfully on unbinding basic jQuery functions.

When the browser is set to be in tablet, the navigation becomes toggled based on click, therefore I disable the linking to any li elements that have a ul.

```
$('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then when the browser is sized above the tablet constraint, I am attempting to reenable the linking functionality with this (I have tried 3 different ways):

```
$('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').unbind('on');

$('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').unbind('click');

$('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').on('click', function(event) {
   return true;
});
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide that might be helpful

Comment: don't unbind 'on', just unbind 'click'

Comment: Doesn't it just enough: `$('.main-navigation .menu a').off('click');` ?

Comment: also with that complicated selector i'd recommend storing it in a variable.

Comment: DLeh, I did try with click, but to no avail. I also simplified the selectors to try 'a' just to hopefully generate a response, that Also was unsuccessful

A. Wolff, the .off function does not seem to disable linking.

Comment: Could you just set a global variable saying if it is in tablet mode or not, and make the click event something like `if(!tabletMode){ event.preventDefault(); }`? Then you don't need to worry about the unbind / rebind shenanigans

Comment: Instead of unbinding, you can just do a if inside the click handler to see if you are in mobile or not and determine the right behaviour

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, there ended up being some sneaky interference with an addition unbinding call above it, where I was trying to unbind a function I had written. If you're interested in my solution, I have provided an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my own problem here. Thought I would post just in case someone else has a similar issue.

My responsive JavaScript has 2 functions per screen size. I had something like this:

```
function tabletInit() {
 // add jQuery that is supposed to fire within these constraints
    function mobileNavInit() {
    var submenus = $('.main-navigation .children');

    submenus.each(function() {
      var parentLink = $(this).prev(),
          parentHref = parentLink.attr('href'),
          overview = '<li class="overview"><a href="'+parentHref+'">Overview</a></li>';

      $(overview).prependTo($(this));
    });

    }

    $('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});

}

function tabletClear() {
 // undo or 'unbind()' anything that should be cancelled out if tablet is sized above

$(overview)unbind('prependTo');
$('.main-navigation .menu > ul > li > a, .main-navigation .menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul) > a').unbind('click');

}
```

The interference was one the unbinding of the overview function. Though the unbinding was performing as needed, it ended up interfering with some of the other JavaScript. So I simply changed it to:

```
$('.overview, .overview2').remove();
```